# Upload file from SP2013 farm to a SP2010 farm list

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I've to make the action in the subject.
I really don't know how to make make it.
Initially I developed a class library on my SP2010 development server that works but when I downloaded this class library on my SP2013 development server the solution doesn't build. I presume becouse in the class library there is the 14 version of Microsoft.SharePoint.

How can I do this job?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will work , as SP2013 will need a Microsoft.SharePoint.dll to have 15.0 version. 
One way to achieve this is to open a project in Visual Studio in SP 2013 environment and then reference the Sharepoint 2013 dll in it. Then create a solution and save it as test_2013.sln

So when you want to generate a class library use this new solution to open your project and then build it

Let me know if this help you

Comment: Now I'm trying to use web services way. I added Lists.asmx as service reference and called it WSLists but I don't find the Lists constructor as I expect https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: At the end I done this task sending the files in an email as attachment to a SP2010 list and processed it.